# What is the best way to request individual characters from a password?

Tags: forms, password, authentication, textbox, banking

Frequently, sites that should really value security (especially banks) ask for several individual characters from a password.

Typically I've seen them do it like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCvY5W.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Is there a better way?

Comment: From a UX point-of-view it's not a bad way of doing it, but from a security perspective you'd be better off having dropdowns for each letter. The reason for this is because if there is a keyboard logger / spyware installed on the machine you can't track what letters get entered if it's from a drop-down. However if it's free text then those entries *can* be logged (which is why, as far as I'm aware anyway) that banks offer this as dropdowns and not free-text.

Comment: @JonW From a security perspective, I'd call this a red flag that they're using reversible encryption instead of hashing - not a very secure way to store passwords.

Comment: Don't. Ask at http://security.stackexchange.com why. (Basically what @Izkata said, but I bet one of the Thomases there will give you an awesome answer - the point is, noone but YOU should know your password, and if you forgot it it should be reset not retrieved)

Comment: To those who are wondering why any site would do this, keep in mind that this is usually (always?) done when there are TWO passwords. First, a secure password used in the normal way and a secondary password where only certain letters are need. The reason for asking for only some letters of the second password is to thwart KEYSTROKE LOGGING as different letters of the password are asked for each time.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: I asked that exact question on security.SE almost two years ago! http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/how-do-some-sites-e-g-online-banks-only-ask-for-specific-characters-from-a-pa I was rather hoping this question would focus more on UX.

Comment: How does the system know my password even _has_ 13 characters? Also, I find that if I try to use this, I need to write out my password and start counting characters. My passwords are more a pattern on the keyboard than a sequence I type consciously. How does that improve security at all?

Comment: @alexmuller I understand your UX aspect, but security first! Your question more concerns with "how to store" than with "is it a good idea" - [How secure is asking for specific characters of passwords instead of the entire thing?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/7467/3272) is a better fit, especially with the accepted answer's quote "Contrary to popular belief, masked password, especially in e-banking sites, though they offer protection from basic keylogging, completely fail to other, more prevalent threats like malware utilizing social engineering.". => **Use two-factor authentication**

Comment: @user27478 That's what a two-factor authentication does, only usually in a way that is not limited to the finite amount character this "second password" has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to complete the login process in two steps.

- Ask the user for the username, which if correct
- Generate the password field asking for only password on the next screen.

[image]

Comment: The problem is in order to validate certain characters, the password would need to be stored in, essentially, plain text which is [a very bad idea](http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/).

Comment: I dont like this because it is easier for an attacker to find a username. If you need to input the combination and give a message "wrong username *or* password" the attacker doesnt know if he found a correct username.

Comment: Ah! I should've mentioned in my answer that this is what Hargreaves Lansdown do. They require your username and DOB before showing the password screen. Thanks for being on the ball!

Answer (score 11):

Jumping in with an answer because I've seen a really nice example of this in the wild. Hargreaves Lansdown is a UK financial institution, and here's how they do it:

[image: Password input screenshot with context]

The idea of giving context to a user hadn't occurred to me before I saw this. In practice, I find it far faster and easier to input a password when I can see how far the requested characters are from each end.

Comment: It might be more usable, yes, but it does give away useful details about the password - the length of it. Knowing the length of a password removes some of the security aspect of it.

Comment: How do they store a password securely and also validate this?

Comment: @JohnGB: I asked exactly that on Security.SE http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/how-do-some-sites-e-g-online-banks-only-ask-for-specific-characters-from-a-pa

Comment: @alexmuller If someone were to get hold of the HSM key, everything may as well be plain text. That's not secure to me.  Another good answer to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226887/password-systems-which-ask-for-individual-letters-what-do-they-store

Answer (score 9):

If any service can validate what the n-th character of your password is, it means that they are storing your password in an **insecure format**. No service should ever know what your password is, they should only be able to say whether your password authenticates or not.

So you shouldn't ever ask for the n-th character of a password, and you shouldn't ever be able to evaluate whether this is the correct character or not.

If you want to authenticate someone, you should **use a full password** stored in a secure way.

Comment: For bank websites this isn't the only form of security. My own bank requests a unique user ID and password when you first log in, and only on successfully getting past that stage are you then prompted to enter characters from your password (which is a different password to the one used to log in).

Comment: @JonW From a UX perspective, what is the benefit of now requiring someone to remember two passwords?

Comment: Well it does not have to mean they store the entire password in an insecure format. Maybe they just store the 4th, 7th & 13th letter of the password reversible. But it does decrease entropy, which undisputedly is bad.

Comment: @JohnGB: Well my assumption would be that people using online banking would not only put up with additional security requirements but would also expect it to some extent. If it's as easy to log onto my Twitter account as it is to log into my bank then (to me at least) I'd feel a bit less secure. There's probably a happy medium in there though - the more security the greater the annoyance, but too little results in lack of trust.

Comment: @Konerak If they store those letters, it means that part of the password is stored insecurely.

Comment: Yes, that is what I said.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question, and I think dismissing this as 'insecure' is looking at the issue from a narrow perspective. This type of security actually solves two important issues: keylogging and, probably more importantly, shoulder surfing. It should be used in combination with another password, though. (My bank asks me to provide a 'secure phrase', rather than a password).

Answer (score 9):

HSBC uses a combination of a username, password, and security key.

In this implementation, you first enter your username.

Next, you are prompted to enter your password and three random characters from your security key:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnnLLm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The benefit of this approach is that the password does not need to be stored in an insecure state.  The interface also does not tell an unauthorized person the length of the security key.

By including disabled text boxes in the interface for the chars not requested, the user can more easily "spell out" their word and provide the correct letter without having to internally visualize the key's individual chars.

The implementation in the question has a much higher cognitive load because the user has to visualize the word and then count places to get the character.

Comment: This is a great design, because it allows users who memorise passwords as paths across the keyboard (e.g. 'Qwertyuiop') to execute the password action without having to work out which letter falls at which position.

Answer (score 6):

You should ask for the entire password, not just because it is more secure, but because users entire passwords by muscle memory, especially passwords made up of arbitrary characters, or defined by movements across the keyboard.  This makes it hard for users to recall characters in specific positions.

Comment: I totally agree. Asking for individual characters of a password is a ridiculous idea!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dropdown here. Using a regular dropdown still allows keyboard input to quickly select the correct character yet makes it easier for users on touch-keyboards and those who prefer to use their mouse.

Comment: Would the drop down need to have a value for every valid char per password policy including upper case, lower case, and special chars like !, @, #, $, %, ^, etc.?

Comment: That depends on your password requirements.